# Deterministic Build C++ Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, deterministic

I have added the Deterministic Flag to the project file for a C++ project, however, when I do a binary compare of the executable, there are still differences between builds with the same source code files. I use this same deterministic flag for my C#/VB.net projects with no issues. 
Flag:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Are there any other settings that need to be changed for the C++ projects to produce an exact binary from the same source code each build?

I am currently using Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.

Below is an image of the comparison, I am not sure what is at location 0x100 and 0x235A0, but the values at these 2 addresses are the only ones that change from build to build.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: Could it be timestamps? The current unix time in hex starts with 0x5aaf. The one at 0x100 could then be `IMAGE_FILE_HEADER.Time­Date­Stamp`.

Comment: The /deterministic compile option is only implemented by the C# compiler.  The linker you use in a C or C++ project has no such option.  So you are seeing the timestamp change in the executable file.  Again for the debug info section, you can get rid of that one.

Comment: I don't understand why this question marked as duplicate, IT'S NOT! the answer is of @HansPassant